# Как отправить в функцию тип класса Kotlin

Tags: классы, kotlin, наследование, типы-данных

У меня есть базовый интерфейс и несколько наследующих его интерфейсов:

```
interface A {/**/}

interface First: A {/**/}
interface Second: A {/**/}
```

Нужно написать функцию, которая должна принимать от меня определенный тип-наследник от A и действовать в зависимости от него. Пояснение в виде кода:

```
fun <C: A> whatType(): Int { // как то так наверное?
    return when(C){ // смотрим, какой из наследников от A я передал
        First -> 1
        Second -> 2
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

И чтобы вызовы функции работали так:

```
val one = whatType<First>() // 1
val two = whatType<Second>() // 2
val zero = whatType<A>() // 0
```

Так же интересно, как правильно реализовать данное общение с экземплярами класса:

```
class One: First {/**/}

val one1 = whatType<One.type>() // как правильно?
```

В качестве альтернативы можно передавать экземпляр класса в функцию

```
fun whatType(type: A): Int {
    return when(type) {
        is First -> 1
        is Second -> 2
        else -> 0
    }
}

val oneExample = One()
val one2 = whatType(oneExample) // 1
```

И данный код будет работать, но хотелось бы избежать передачи полноценных экземпляров классов внутрь функции

*UPD* Как это все выглядит в общем виде:

```
// ---- первый интерфейс

interface A {/**/} // главный интерфейс
interface First: A {/**/} // наследники
interface Second: A {/**/} 

Class One: First {/**/} // реализация наследника

// ---- второй интерфейс

interface Z { // сторонний интерфейс, в котором нужно реализовать метод 
    fun <C: A> whatType(): Int //????

    inline fun <reifield C :A> whatTypeInl(): Int // ругается и предлагает вынести ниже
}

inline fun <reifield C :A> Z.whatTypeInl(): Int {return 0} // выносит сюда и требует тело

interface testOne: Z {
    override fun <C: A> whatType(): Int {/*делает when()*/} //???

    override fun <reifield C :A> Z.whatTypeInl(): Int {} // не понимаю как это можно сделать, не выходит.
}

interface testTwo: Z{/*аналогично*/} // реализовываться будут только конечные наследники всех интерфейсов и взаимодействовать между собой

class FirstZ: testOne {/**/} 


main(){ // какая то главная функция в которой все происходит
    val x = One() //A::First
    val y = FirstZ() //Z::testOne

    var z: Int = y.whatType<x>() // ?? как правильно ??
}
```

Грубо говоря, у меня будут уникальные действия внутри метода whatType для каждого набора наследников Z и A

Comment: А если класс реализует оба интерфейса? Для чего вообще вам нужна такая функция?

Comment: Суть в том, что у меня каждый класс реализуют только один из интерфейсов-наследников, и в определенный момент мне нужно узнать, какой именно из наследников у меня здесь сейчас, и в зависимости от этого уже сделать что нужно.

Comment: а почему бы не использовать полиморфизм? т.е. сделать абстрактный метод в интерфейсе и реализовывать его в классах и вызывать этот метод

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос, там как раз функция с доступом к классу генерика.

Comment: @IR42, не совсем понимаю, что именно вы предлагаете. Я сейчас добавил как бы полный код, укажите пожалуйста конкретнее, я вот совсем не понимаю

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, я перечитал ваш ответ там, попробовал сделать - не получилось. Я добавил полный код, чтобы было понятнее. Я наворотил сложную штуку из интерфейсов, и все кроме вот таких доступов типов-наследников работает как мне надо.

Comment: `reifield` может быть только у `inline` функций, а они могут быть только `final` или `private`.

Answer (score 1):

В интерфейс вы такую функцию не вставите, как extension function да.
Вот вполне валидный код.

```
interface A {/* */} // главный интерфейс

inline fun <reified C: A> A.whatType(): KClass<C> {
    return C::class
}

class Test: A {
    val myKotlinClass = whatType<Test>() // Test::class
}
```

Нужны вам не сами Kotlin классы, а константы, допишите.